# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' for Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have create an Azure Function and trying to Authenticate by Azure Key Vaults and certificate In my Azure function I wrote a code to save the data into SharePoint List (Online),it is working fine in Localhost data is getting save by service account but when I am calling the Azure function on web or by button click in from the SharePoint frame work it is giving me below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhnCo.png)

I have added cors in the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is usually accessed via Multi Factor Authentication (MFA). Also note that it's necessary to create certificate for Azure AD App for authentication, ClientSecret method has been blocked by SharePoint Online currently.

So, it won't work properly unless you create a service connection in Azure Active Directory without MFA and use it to access the SharePoint. **Service accounts** and **service principals** are normally used by back-end services allowing programmatic access to applications, but are also used to sign in to systems for administrative purposes

Service account without MFA are least privileged account. It would be required to create one, then you can use it to access SharePoint. It's not possible to access the SharePoint using the default MFA based account of user.

Please check the [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) document for more information.